# Is there a way to iterate on all Drupal modules on d.o?

Tags: version-control, community-official-site

I'd like to iterate on all contrib modules, pull their repos and extract information (such as drush commands, graph dependencies, etc.)

Is there a way to list all modules, other than scraping https://drupal.org/project/project_module?

Comment: The update module from drupal core does some of what you want so it might be useful to check out its code. Scraping drupal and drupalcode sites is probably what you'll need to do though to get the level of detail you want in your info.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sandbox module (from a Drupal user I trust) that does it:
https://drupal.org/sandbox/greggles/1481160

Comment: Spoke too soon: This module downloads the modules specified in a list file, but does not retrieve the list from Drupal.org.

Answer (score 0):

There's an old issue asking for a mechanism to pull entire codebase: 
[Provide a way to download the entire git codebase for all projects](https://www.drupal.org/node/1057386). It includes several ways to get it, some of them don't work - I guess because the upgrade of drupal.org to Drupal 7.